# Badges on smart phone have different color lettering

Tags: bug, badges, design, mobile-web

I came to notice that on the smart phone (using mobile web theme), some of the badges some have white lettering and some have blue/orange lettering:

> [image]

The badges are hyperlinks, so the change of color means different color for the "visited" links. However, in the full site theme the color does not change, so it looks like a bug.

Comment: Can you show us a picture of this?

Comment: I have reworded this into a full bug report, making it clear what is wrong. /cc @quartata.

Comment: It is a duplicate since it is about a bug in color

Comment: @PythonMaster I don't think so, as this one here is specific to mobile theme, and I can't see this happening anywhere else.

Comment: The duplicate is also about mobile theme